# Vagrant / puppet config for complex vhost setting (if statements etc.)?

Tags: nginx, vagrant, puppet

I setup my vagrant box via a pre-configured https://puphpet.com/ package with PHP 5.4 and Nginx.

After provisioning, I always have to change the vhost_autogen.conf by myself - I guess that cannot be the idea behind vagrant and puppet :-) How can I:

- remove the vhost_autogen.conf automatically and replace it with another one

OR

- add the settings below as puppet configuration?

This is the required vhost setting:

> server {
>
> listen *:80;
>
> server_name example.dev www.example.dev;
>
> root /var/www/example.com;
>
> index index.php;
>
> access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.de.access.log;
>
> error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;
>
> if ($host ~* www.(.*)) {
>          set $host_without_www $1;
>          rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www$1 permanent; #1
>          #rewrite ^ $scheme://$host_without_www$1request_uri permanent; #2
>      }
>
> # Rewrite for minify
>      rewrite ^/min/([a-z]=.*) /min/index.php?$1 last;
>
> # canonicalize codeigniter url end points
>
> if ($request_uri ~* ^(/start(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$)
>      {
>          rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;
>      }
>
> # removes trailing "index" from all controllers
>      if ($request_uri ~* index/?$)
>      {
>          rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
>      }
>
> # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
>      if (!-d $request_filename)
>      {
>          rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
>      }
>
> # removes access to "system" folder, also allows a "System.php" controller
>      if ($request_uri ~* ^/system)
>      {
>          rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
>          break;
>      }
>
> # unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
>      if (!-e $request_filename)
>      {
>          rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
>          break;
>      }
>
> # catch all
>      error_page 404 /index.php;
>
> location / {
>          root  /var/www/example.com;
>          rewrite ^/min/([a-z]=.*) /min/index.php?$1 last;
>      }
>
> location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
>      location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
>      location ~ /.          { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
>      location ~ ~$           { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
>
> location ~ .php$ {
>          root  /var/www/example.com;
>          try_files  $uri  $uri/  /index.php?$args ;
>          index  index.html index.htm index.php;
>          fastcgi_index index.php;
>          fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
>          fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
>          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
>          fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
>
> ```
>    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
>    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
>    include fastcgi_params;
> ```
>
> }
>   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `puppet/manifest.pp`, search for `create_resources(nginx_vhost, $nginx_values['vhosts'])`, replace it with the following:

```
  file { "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my-site.conf":
  source => '/full/path/to/conf/file',
  owner  => 'root',
  group  => 'root',
  mode   => '0644'
  }
```